# Can we construct $g(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \, dx<\varepsilon$ without Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$, and forall $\varepsilon>0$,  can we construct a continuously differentiable function $g(x)$ such that $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \, dx<\varepsilon$ without using Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: How would you use the Weierstrass approximation theorem? $f$ is not necessarily continuous. Polynomials are dense in $L^1[a,b]$ but I am guessing that is not an acceptable proof here.

Comment: Usually you convolve $f$ with a mollifier.

Comment: @copper.hat we can easily construct a piecewise linear function $h(x)$ such that $\int_a^b |f(x)-h(x)|dx<e/2$ then use the weierstrass approximation theorem for $h(x)$.

Comment: How explicit do you want to be? A mollifier argument is more direct, but you can be a bit more explicit by starting from a piecewise constant approximation and then using splines to smooth out the jumps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. The idea is straightforward, the details tedious.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, there is some partition $P$ such that
$U(f,p) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$.

Suppose the partition is $x_0=1,x_1,...,x_n=b$. Define the (discontinuous) step function $l(x) = \inf_{t \in [x_k,x_{k+1}]} f(t) $ for $x \in [x_k,x_{k+1})$ and $l(b) = l(x_{n-1})$.

For convenience extend $f$ to the right by defining $f(x) = f(b)$.

Note that $l$ is Riemann integrable, $f(x) \ge l(x)$ for all $x$, and
$\int_a^b l(x) dx = L(f,P)$, so $\int_a^b |f(x)-l(x)| dx < \epsilon$.

Now we need to smooth the function $l$ out a bit:

Given an integrable function $f$ and $\tau>0$, define $\sigma_{f,\epsilon}$ as follows;
$\sigma_{f,\tau} (x) = { 1\over \tau} \int_x^{x+\tau} f(t) dt$.

(Aside: Note that we can write $\sigma_{f,\tau} = f \star {1 \over \tau } 1_{[-\tau,0]}$.)

A little work shows that if $l$ is a step function, then $ \sigma_{l,\tau} $ is a
piecewise 'linear' function. Furthermore, if $l$ is bounded by $M$, then
$\int_a^b |l(x)-\sigma_{l,\tau}(x)| dx \le 2 (n+1)\tau M$, in particular, we can
pick $\tau$ such that $\int_a^b |l(x)-\sigma_{l,\tau}(x)| dx < \epsilon$. Let $l_1 = \sigma_{l,\tau}$.

Now repeat the process, note that if $h$ is continuous then
$\sigma_{h,\tau}$ is continuously differentiable and since
$h(x)-\sigma_{h,\tau}(x) = {1 \over \tau} \int_x^{x+\tau} (h(x)-h(t)) dt $,
we see that $h$ converges to $\sigma_{h,\tau}$ uniformly and so
$\lim_{\tau \to 0} \int_a^b |h(x)-\sigma_{h,\tau}(x)| dx = 0$.

As above,
choose $\tau$ such that
$\int_a^b |l_1(x)-\sigma_{{l_1},\tau}| dx < \epsilon$, and let $l_2 = \sigma_{{l_1},\tau}$.

Then $\int_a^b |f(x)-l_2(x)| dx < 3 \epsilon$.

Comment: Could you explain how $l$ was "smoothed" into a continuous function. I don't really see how we get a continuous function from the step function.

Comment: Look at the formula for $\sigma_{f,\tau}$. If $f$ is bounded  then $\sigma_{l,\tau}$ is continuous (this is true more generally). You can try an explicit example to convince yourself, the proof is straightforward. In general, if $f$ is $C^k$ then $\sigma_{f,\tau}$ is $C^{k+1}$, the latter would follow from Leibniz's rule.